# can we say "they have suggested to them"

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I am narrating a situation whereby some group A of people suggested something to another group of people B. Can I say "They suggested them" or "they suggested to them to use" bla bla bla..

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question could really benefit from a full sample sentence, so I'm guessing a little bit, but you would **not** say "They suggested them" in that context.  You **could** say "They suggested to them to use Google instead", but this is a bit clunky and not idiomatic.  It would be better to say

"They suggested that they should use Google instead"

or

"They suggested they use Google instead." (terser)

or

"They suggested to them that they should use Google instead." (longer but more comprehensible).

You can use "They suggested them" in a different context, eg

"Who suggested them?"  "**They** suggested them."